# Is it safe to wrap Mac cord with a cloth?

Tags: mac, magsafe, charger

Okay so the cord from the brick has teared a bit and the charger only works on certain angles lol..

[image]
[image]

So what i did to hold the cord together was tying a cloth around it. I wanted to know is that safe? Or should I tie an IDE cable?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are referring to a Macbook brick.

The thin (low voltage) side is either 14.5V (Air) or 20V (Pro). I don't know about the USB-C connector.

Cloth **MIGHT** be safe on the low voltage side if just the covering separated, but if it has to be in a specific position to work, you probably have a broken wire as well which could lead to sparking under the wrong conditions.

The only *truly* safe thing to do is replace your adapter. You can use proper electrical tape until then, but it should only be a temporary measure.

If it's on the other side of the brick, replace immediately.